# Does the way you import matter?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there any difference for the finally compiled production code if I import like this:

`import * as _ from 'lodash';
_.find(stuff,['whatever', something]);`

Or like this:

`import { find } from 'lodash';
find(stuff,['whatever', something]);`

I mean, does the code get smaller with version b or is it just the same for the compiled, bundled version?

The code and lodash is just for explanation purposes. The question applies to all and any modules.

Comment: *Theoretically* the latter one can be [*tree shaken*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_shaking) to omit anything from `lodash` you didn't import. Whether there's a tool that can accurately do that in practice is a different question.

Comment: I think it should be easy to test, isn't it? Compile both of them and compare their sizes :)

Comment: I've tried 'something'. I did it as second version of code in TS and in the compiled JS version (compiled with `tsc`) it ended up being `const lodash_1 = require("lodash");` and it got 'translated' to the first version of code. :(

Comment: I've also tried to bundle stuff with webpack and it seems all the lodash lib gets in there as well.

Comment: As @deceze comments the tree shaken is the main advantage of using a scoped import, there are many ways to do it: Typescript + es2015, Babel, Webpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My conclusion after playing with compiling the two versions is that is does not matter!
The outputted version is the same size and in our case contains the whole `lodash` lib or a reference to it in the form of `const some_variable = require("lodash");`

What really makes a difference is if you do it like this:

```
import find from 'lodash/find';
find(stuff,['whatever', something]);
```

This only picks a little part of the library and does indeed save space.

It should be noted that I don't know tricks and have not played with bundlers that may have options to handle the creation of the import.

Please correct me if I am wrong!